# Push Notifications with Conversational Webhook

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to get permission to send push notifications on Google Assistant through the conversational webhook.

I'm following the steps [here under Actions SDK JSON](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#asdk-node)

I have the first part with "Hi! Welcome to Push Notifications" working.

Then I send the second response under the ask for the UPDATE permission.

The problem is that it seems this is triggering some event on the google assistant side where it asks again for permission to send notifications [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lV55.png)

I think this requires me to define some other intent but how do I properly handle this so it will send me the request with the userID?

Comment: Did you read through the entire page of the documentation? It seems like rest of explains how to handle the permission.

Comment: Yup it was just an error on my end where I wasn't carrying over the conversation ID. It works now.